# gdx-setup.jar is not an executable jar file .

Tags: libgdx

My gdx-setup.jar file is downloaded but it is not an executable jar file , so it doesn't show the project generator interface on double clicking. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you have JRE properly installed? Can you open another .jar files?

Comment: can u atleast put the error log.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
kindly follow these guidelines. there can we 1000s of possibilites for your problem. Kindly put all the error logs and what all u did to solve it and the link from where u get the jar